# Having two text fields on one line in a form

Tags: list, custom-list, custom-form, form

In my form I want to have a salary range, so I would like to have 2 text fields on one line of the form.

Also I would like a text field and a drop down list on the same line of the form.

I'm assuming they have to be in different columns, but is there anyway to put them on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Infopath, you can edit the existing new, edit and display forms for a list, or create your own ones and getting the results you are asking for. Editing the existing ones, you could be done in the matter of minutes.

[Customize a SharePoint List form using InfoPath](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/infopath-help/customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-HA101821257.aspx)

**Update:** I saw your other post about InfoPath being discontinued in the future but add it here as well. [Keeping-infopath-after-an-update](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104080/keeping-infopath-after-an-update)

> How long will InfoPath be supported?
>
> The InfoPath 2013 client will be supported through April 2023.
>   InfoPath Forms Services for SharePoint Server 2013 will be supported
>   until April 2023. InfoPath Forms Services in Office 365 will be
>   supported until further notice.