# keeping infopath after an update

Tags: infopath, upgrade

I have heard that they are no longer going to use InfoPath in sharepoint.
I have numerous InfoPath forms I was just wondering how that would affect them with upgrading. My thinking is I won't be able to use them obviously, but am hoping I am wrong

Comment: From where have you heard this? Is this on any microsoft site?

Comment: my boss, apparently they are phasing it out

Comment: Yes InfoPath will be discontinued in future releases of sharepoint. It was a big buzz around this at the latest SP conference. See here for example regarding available (and not yet available) substitutes http://zimmergren.net/business/the-future-of-forms-with-sharepoint-and-office-365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any issue in upgrading, But in reality this is the technology which disconnected.

In an effort to streamline our investments and deliver a more integrated Office forms user experience, we’re retiring InfoPath and investing in new forms technology across SharePoint, Access, and Word. This means that InfoPath 2013 is the last release of the desktop client, and InfoPath Forms Services in SharePoint Server 2013 is the last release of InfoPath Forms Services. The InfoPath Forms Services technology within Office 365 will be maintained and it will function until further notice.

In other Words, Still we can use the infopath for 2013 and their support from MSFT will end on 2023.

How long will InfoPath be supported?

- The InfoPath 2013 client will be supported through April 2023.
- InfoPath Forms Services for SharePoint Server 2013 will be supported
  until April 2023.
- InfoPath Forms Services in Office 365 will be supported until further
  notice.

What should I use to build and complete forms?

- You should continue to use InfoPath technology.

What will the new forms capabilities be in SharePoint, Access, and Word? When will they be available?

- We’ll be sharing updates throughout the year, with a sneak peek in
  March at the SharePoint Conference.

http://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the retirement of InfoPath was announced by Microsoft, but it's a slow retirement that won't be complete until 2023. Microsoft discussed their roadmap and the alternatives at the SharePoint Conference session in March.

You can [view the video and read a summary with key slides here.](http://www.formotus.com/16863/infopath-alternatives/spc348-microsoft-alternatives-infopath-video)

The client application (Designer and Filler) is to be supported until 2023. The Forms Services piece that lets InfoPath forms show in a browser should continue to work as long as you are using SharePoint 2013 or earlier. Support for Forms Services in future versions of SharePoint is unclear. SharePoint Online will stop supporting Forms Services at some point after a one-year notice (search 'InfoPath one year notice' and you should find my source on that).

One of the InfoPath alternatives promoted by Microsoft is the 3rd party solution from Formotus. Formotus has committed to support InfoPath-designed forms for the long term in its mobile form-filler apps, and has [announced plans to develop its own form-design solution as a successor to InfoPath Designer](http://www.formotus.com/16831/blog-news/because-infopath-formotus-promotes-migration-to-new-windows-8-app).